# Deserialize JSON text to a specific object type using the Type name

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net

I used to deserialize JSON text to a strongly type object using the code below

```
Trainer myTrainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Trainer>(sJsonText);
```

Now I need to convert deserialize JSON text to a specific type knowing only the name of the type.

I tried to use Reflection to get the Type from its name then use this type with JsonConvert as shown below:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("Trainer");
var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myType >(sJsonText);
```

but unfortunately, the error below shown up:

```
CS0118  'myType' is a variable but is used like a type
```

Is there a way that I can make reference to a class using a string?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use  [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, Type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm):

```
var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sJsonText, myType);
```

Or if you prefer

```
dynamic jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sJsonText, myType);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dbc it works like a charm.
but I still need to know a way to make reference to a class using a string as I want to pass myType to [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: @HebaGomaah - use `MakeGenericMethod`.  See [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method).

Comment: thanks a lot that is exactly what I was looking for.